# Left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java, android

For the following method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if(v.getId() != R.id.listViewToDo) {
        return;
    }

    menu.setHeaderTitle("What will you like to do?");
    String[] options = ( "Delete Task", "Return" );

    for(String option : options) {
        menu.add(option);
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

> the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like your syntax could be wrong around the "=" operator (the assignment operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply did not initialize the array correctly:

```
String[] options = ( "Delete Task", "Return" );
```

Replace the `()` by `{}` to get:

```
String[] options = { "Delete Task", "Return" };
```

You can further refer to [Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) to get more info on how to initialize an array.

(Also next time, please indicate the line in your code with the error - it would have been faster to spot the error this way)

Comment: @Samuel sure no problem :). Remember to mark as answered ;)

Answer (score 7):

Your array initialization is invalid. Array initialization expressions require curly braces.

Change:

```
String[] options = ( "Delete Task", "Return" );
```

to:

```
String[] options = { "Delete Task", "Return" };
```